# Yii search from function

Tags: search, yii, cgridview

I have a CGridView and I want to search in it. The thing is that I have a column that is modified by a function in my model. Everything start in the search.php view that contains a cgridview that looks like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'grid-demande',
'summaryText'=>'',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
//'filter'=>$model,
'cssFile'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/css/my_gridview.css",
'columns'=>array
(
array(            
        'name'=>'id_post',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'16%'),
    ),
array(            
        'name'=>'fk_authorid',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'16%'),
        'value'=>array($this,'renderNameDmd'),
    ),
)
```

As you can see the function renderNameDmd is called to render the name of the author. This function is in my model but is called from the controller:

```
protected function renderNameDmd($data,$row)
{
$model=$this->loadModelDmd($data->id_post);
return $model->getChAuthor();   
}
```

And in the model class I call:

```
public function getChAuthor(){ 
    $modelUsr=TUsers::model()->findByPk($this->fk_authorid);
return $this->fk_authorid.', '.$modelUsr->ch_completeName;
}
```

Everything works fine for displaying. My main problem is that I want to search through this cgridview and I can't search with the values that are displayed. Here is my search function that is contained in my model:

```
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

            //more criterias

    $criteria->compare('fk_cip',$this->fk_cip,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

For the moment, I have tried a couple of things but nothing worked so I reseted the code to what it was initialy. For now, if I search through my cgridview I can only filter with the *authorid* and not the full column format I wrote. Exemple:

For a row that looks like this:

> 3231, John Doe

I can only search through the:

> 3231

---

I want to search through the row I created from the function. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can't search for column like that. The problem is that dataprovider constructs query, and executes it in sql. You don't have that function in db. Either denormalize database to save name on `save` function, or make search with relations (im not good at it so cant halp with that). Also this is very inneficient, as it performs query for each row. Also post you `relations` function of model, so we could check if relations are ok.

Comment: Oh well... I'm looking for an alternative to my current solution then!

Comment: Relational search could work, but im not using relational db's so i dont know how to do this. Alternatively you could search `TUsers`, get matched id's and use it for search in other model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Yii is quite handy for this kind of feature, but you should first rewrite your model to use relations.

In your model :

```
// this attribute will be used in search function
private $_authorName;

public function rules()
{
    return array (
        .....
        array('authorName', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        .....
    );
}

public function relations()
{
    return array(
        .....
        'author' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TUsers', 'fk_authorid'),
        .....
    );
}

// authorName getter
public function getAuthorName()
{
    if ($this->scenario=='search')
        return $this->_authorName;

    return $this->fk_authorid.', '.$this->author->ch_completeName;
}

// authorName setter
public function setAuthorName($authorName) { 
    $this->_authorName = $authorName;
}

public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    .....

    // search author name ?
    if ($this->authorName!==null)
    {
        $criteria->with = array('author');
        $criteria->compare('author.ch_completeName', $this->authorName, true);
    }

    .....

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

And in your CGridView, you should simply define your column like this :

```
array(            
    'name'=>'authorName',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'16%'),
),
```

And you should read this :
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will take a look at it and read the source!